# How to get Laravel Blade value as an Array data using Post Method?

Tags: laravel

I Have a Blade Form that will execute Post Method, this is my blade

```
@foreach ($dataku as $row => $order)
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <b>{{ $order->delivery_order_no }}</b>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="order[{{ $row }}][do_id]" value="{{ $order->id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="order[{{ $row }}][so_id]" value="{{ $order->sales_order->id }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="table-responsive m-t-40" style="clear:both;">
                                    <table class="table table-hover" style="font-size: 9pt;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr><th class="text-center">No</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">SKUID</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Item Name</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">UOM</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Qty So</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Qty Do</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Qty Confirm</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Qty Minus</th>
                                                <th class="text-center">Remark Confirm</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach ($order->delivery_order_details as $do =>$detOrder )
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $detOrder->skuid }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $detOrder->sales_order_detail->item_name }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $detOrder->uom->name  }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $detOrder->sales_order_detail->qty }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $detOrder->qty_do }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="order[{{ $row }}][detail[][{{ $do }}][skuid]]" value="{{  $detOrder->skuid}}">
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="order[{{ $row }}][detail[][{{ $do }}][qty_do]]" value="{{ $detOrder->qty_do  }}">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="order[{{ $row }}][detail[][{{ $do }}][qty_minus]]" value="0">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Remark Confirm" class="form-control" name="order[{{ $row }}][detail[][{{ $do }}][remarks]]">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>     
                @endforeach
```

I Just want to get the data from  the blade as an array ,... and then this is my controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
    { 
        return $request->all();  
    }
```

I Get The Data Like This

[image: array]

is the return value from my blade `$request->all();` correct? looks like something wrong ???

Comment: Nothing wrong here, the orders contains 2 array. The first array also contains 4 array (details). The 2nd array contains 1 array (details).

Comment: okey,... thanks before, looks like something worng in  `detail [:` specificly in  `[` is that not wrong

Comment: Would be `name="order[{{ $row }}][detail][{{ $do }}][qty_minus]"` not `name="order[{{ $row }}][detail[][{{ $do }}][qty_minus]]"`

Comment: Yes its Work Perfectly,... Thanks @sta

Answer (score 2):

[@sta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575350/sta) provided an answer but I would make it more detailed:

When you build more complex structure (nested) in a html form input, every next key or list has to be surrounded by `[]`.

So if you do just a nested keys it will be `something[key1][key2][key3]`.
And if you do an array and a nested keys it will be `something[key1][key2][][key3]`, where `[]` means that `[key2]` will be an array (and every array element will have a `key3` key with provided value in input `value` attribute.

That's why this input name can't work:
`order[0][detail[][0][skuid]]`
but this one will work:
`name="order[0][detail][0][qty_minus]`

Comment: but how about  `<input type="hidden" name="order[{{ $row }}][do_id]" value="{{ $order->id }}">` ? can we change to `order[0][do_id]` ?

Comment: I used `[0]` because i didin't want to use `{{ $row }}` in comment :) If you have a loop - you have to use `{{ $row }}` in this case because if your input name is or has an array, every element of this array must have different key like `[0][id]`,`[1][id]` , `[2][id]` etc